# Style sheet not being used when printing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, printing

I am having a stylesheet specific to print. In print i want a logo and want a background color for it. In chrome it works fine, but IE it does not. Any specific code needs to be added?

Comment: There is a setting on the Print and Print Preview dialogs to print background images.... There is a setting on the Advance tab of Internet Options to "Block unsecured images with other mixed content"

Comment: To set up your dev environment in IE, go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes.... IE's dev tool will now list any (otherwise suppressed) messages for markup errors, blocked content and security warnings.

Comment: File>Page Setup.... there is a checkbox to "Print background images"